# UICollectionViewCell: How to Center Cells For UICollectonView

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a 2-item UICollectionView and I want them to move in a way that whenever the user swipes to the next cell the cell is **centered** and at any given point, **only one cell is seen.**

How do I go about doing this programmatically? Also, how do I do this so that it remains the same if I were to switch the simulator to a different iPhone?

[image: Here is what I have so far, as you can see the orange cell is not centered.]

Comment: Are you adding some type of margin like constraints or insets?. An approach is to make the cell's have the same width as the screen and inset the contentView of the cell

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller as collection view's delegate. Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your view controller and provide `sizeForItem` as below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: cellHeight))
}
```

Set section insets and line spacing:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return .zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```